# When creating a function using the turtle module, Python says my turtle name variable is not defined

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

I am making a function draw_square that draws a square using turtle. It takes (t,side_length) where t is turtle name and side_length is the side length. However when testing in thonny using `draw_square(dave,50)` it says name 'dave' is not defined

Tried importing turtle before creating my function

```
import turtle
def draw_square(t, side_length):
        """Use the turtle t to draw a square with side_length."""

        t=turtle.Turtle()
        t.forward(side_length)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(side_length)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(side_length)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(side_length)
        t.right(90)
```

**Expected result**:

draws a square of predetermined length after giving turtle name and length.

**Actual result**:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dave' is not defined"
```

Comment: Where do you define/set "dave"?

Comment: in thonny in the interactive shell, i am typing: draw_square(dave,50)

Comment: This doesn't set the variable "dave".

Comment: oh, i thought thats how you set them for functions that I create - we just covered this in class. I'll do some more research on this topic. If you dont mind me asking, how do I set the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have most of the pieces, you just need to arrange them in a slightly different order:

```
import turtle

def draw_square(t, side_length):
    """ Use the turtle t to draw a square with side_length. """

    t.forward(side_length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(side_length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(side_length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(side_length)
    t.right(90)

dave = turtle.Turtle()

draw_square(dave, 50)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works great! I see what I did wrong, i get the whole structure thing now.